# How to get list of network requests URL done in HTML (browser background)

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

How can I get list of requests URLs done in "background" (devtools in chrome)? (Javascript or Java)

For example I would like to get OrderID from  this [Request URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnv8C.png)

Unfortunately I can't use proxy

I found only how I can get response, but some informations I can get only from Request URL or Request body

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(value) {
   this.addEventListener("progress", function(){
       console.log("Loading");
   }, false);

   this.addEventListener("load", function(){
       console.log(this.responseText);
   }, false);
   this.realSend(value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this and I get all I want

```
const observer2 = new PerformanceObserver((entries) => {
  entries.getEntriesByType("resource").forEach(res => console.log(res.toJSON()))
});
observer2.observe({ entryTypes: ["resource"] });
```